# How to disable test discovery in visual studio 2017?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have some solutions with a bunch of projects and we have no unit test project in these solutions.  However Visual Studio 2017 is still trying to discover unit tests and slowing down our process.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tQgf.jpg

I looked at the runsettings xml file but there was nothing in there to disable it

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file

any idea how we turn this unnecessary stuff off for some of our solutions?

Thanks

Comment: I feel this is just getting worse.  In VS2019 my 70-project solution builds in a crawl because hundreds of test discovery processes ("dotnet vstest ... /ListTests") are running on any assembly touched. MS must be testing this on toy projects...

Answer (score 1):

This was driving me crazy too.  One day it just started running test discovery after every build, and switching my output pane to "Test" which is annoying.

How I fixed it in VS 2015 (may be the same for 2017),
**disable (uncheck) this setting**:

```
Test menu --> Test Settings --> Keep Test Execution Engine Running
```

[image]